# How can I configure logstash to parse G1GC loggc files

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, g1gc

In our production environment, we have an ELK stack, which we are using for monitoring our own log files.

We also have enabled g1-gc logging:

```
-Xloggc:${PATH_TO_LOG}/${FILE_PREFIX}-g1-gc.log
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:GCLogFileSize=10M
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

But, we are not yet analysing these log files.  We are interested in having logstash process these files, so that we can begin making use of them.

Are there any example logstash input configurations that will work with the G1GC log files?

Thanks

Comment: I searched but could not find anything related. But you can use grok to create customized patterns: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping somebody out there had already done it. :)

Comment: Maybe to make it easier for people to help you, you could update your question with a relevant portion of the log you wish to grok.

Comment: Don't know if this is still needed, but there seems to be a project doing this on github: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file